# How to render different tab content on different facebook pages, by using the same Page Tab App in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Is there any way, through which I can render different page tabs for different facebook pages, by using the same "page tab app".

**Something like:**

```
For FB Page "Blah" the app should render the page from the url "http://www.mywebsite.com/Blah"

For FB Page "Blah-Blah" the app should render the page from the url "http://www.mywebsite.com/Blah-Blah"

For FB Page "Blah-Blah-Blah" the app should render the page from the url "http://www.mywebsite.com/Blah-Blah-Blah"
```

**Can I achieve this by using the same facebook app?**

Answer (score 2):

In PHP it is very simple. Get [signedRequest](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getSignedRequest/) ([this is how the array will look like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)) and find out where the app is loaded from.
Don't forget that the app can be loaded via ht*tp://apps.facebook.com/AppNameSpace so there will be no key page. (I had to add * in the link because I am new here so I couldn't post this because it contains more than 2 links.)

```
if(isset($signedRequest['page']))
{
    switch($signedRequest['page'])
    {
        case 'pageID1':
            //code
        break;

        case 'pageID2':
            //code
        break;
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I read about signed_request, but I think it is used to recognize the user which is visiting your app on facebook. Like you can control that, what will appear before we get the signed_request(anonymus user), and what will appear after when we get the signed_request(recognized user), by passing the signed_request value as a part of URL's query string. Because I know for a page tab app you can specify only one URL in "Page Tab URL" option, and then you have to do "Save changes". How am I suppose to give that URL as a variable value in "Page Tab URL" option, when it demands for a fixed URL value?